# If $f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)+x^2y+xy^2$ and $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{f(x)}{x}=1, (x,y \in R)$, find $f(0),f'(0),f'(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

Let$$x = 0$$ s.t.$$f(y) = f(0) + f(y),$$ s.t $$f(0) = f(y) - f(y) = 0$$

thus $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{f(x)}{x} = \lim_{x\to0} \frac{f(x+0)-f(0)}{x} = f'(0)=1$$

Now let$$ \lim_{y\to0} \frac{f(y)}{y} = 1 $$

s.t. $$y \to 0$$ $$f(y) = y$$ s.t $$f(x+y) = f(x) + y $$ $$\frac{f(x+y)-f(x)}{y} = 1 $$  thus$$\lim_{y\to0}\frac{f(x+y)-f(x)}{y} = 1$$ $$f'(x)=1$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Take $x=0 ,y=0$

Then $f(0+0)=f(0)+f(0)$
Therefore $f(0)=0$.
Now $lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x+0)-f(0)}{x-0}=1$
.Thus $f'(0)=1$.

There is a mistake in your solution.See the below mentioned property

${\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{{f\left( x \right)}}{{g\left( x \right)}} }={ \frac{{\lim\limits_{x \to a} f\left( x \right)}}{{\lim\limits_{x \to a} g\left( x \right)}},\;\;\;}\kern-0.3pt {\text{if}\;\;\lim\limits_{x \to a} g\left( x \right) \ne 0.}$
 Can you finish from here?

Comment: i think now my steps are correct

Comment: How $f(y)=y$? See my recent edit.

Comment: hmm what about now?

Comment: @Heng Wei $f'(x)=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{f(x+y)-f(x)}{y}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{f(y)}{y}+x^2+xy=1+x^2$